# Does a pair of USB-tethered ESP32 (or cp210x) modules connected to each other need optoisolation?

Tags: opto-isolator

Let's suppose I want to build a 21st-century null modem using a pair of ESP32 modules (or maybe just a pair of cp210x usb-to-serial modules) connected "back to back" (tx on one to rx on the other, and vice-versa), with the modules themselves plugged into two different computers' USB ports for power & host communication.

Can I just wire the two modules directly together, or do they need optoisolaton...  to protect the two USB ports, or facilitate reliable communication? Or can I safely take for granted that computer USB power & signal levels are *very* tightly specified and controlled, to the point where any voltage difference between them will be almost meaningless?

Comment: Why would two ESP32 be needed? As USB-serial interfaces? If you want to make 21st century null modem with USB to serial adapters, why would you use such slow chips as simple USB HS serial chips have at least 12 Mbps UARTs.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't need optoisolation; the ground potential of two USB hosts close enough to each other that you can connect them with a USB cable will be close enough to each other.

> Or can I safely take for granted that computer USB power & signal levels are very tightly specified and controlled, to the point where any voltage difference between them will be almost meaningless?

The precise potential is meaningless anyways for signaling in USB, since communication is done in a differential way (completely in superspeed, approximately in older versions of USB). The ground potentials might differ slightly before, but connecting the cable would inherently make a current flow through the shield that compensates that. That's not *great* if potential differences were high, but that can't be the case: USB Host ground potentials will either be isolated from anything else, or close to the potential of protective earth, and thus practically the same for co-located devices.

Answer (score 0):

No, two devices connected together with cables, does not require optoisolation.

Not for USB or for any other interface.

Monitors and other devices connect to PCs without optoisolation. Monitors may have USB hubs and they also connect to PCs without optoisolation.

Audio cables also have no optoisolation.

Only interface that is isolated is Ethernet. But only the data pins. If you put a shielded cable between two desktop PCs, the grounds of two PCs will be connected through the shield.

However, you can optoisolate them if you want to.